# Using Git.php to a project

Tags: php, git, github, gitlab

Anyone of you already use this [Git.ph](https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php)? I'm having a hard time to setup this in my project. Already tried `$repo = Git::open('https://github.com/cristianumali22/Test-Project.git');` but the output is `"https://github.com/cristianumali22/Test-Project.git" does not exist` Is it possible to integrate this to Github or Gitlab? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git can only work with repositories available at the local filesystem. Repositories at remote URLs are contacted to clone/fetch/pull/push and nothing more. SO you have to clone a repository locally and open it with `$repo = Git::open('/path/to/repo');`

Gitlab/Github/Bitbucket have API that extend git and allow to work with remote repositories but the library cannot use that API so you only can use local clones.

Comment: can you give me a link where I can have an API for Gitlab? Thank you!